# Trying to disable a button onPress - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm kinda new to ReactJs, I'm trying to disable a button in my app when that button is pressed. I have a function called  "disableButtonEG"  but it does nothing when I pressed it.

```
 function disableButtonEG= () => {
        button.disabled = true
   };

<Button
                title="Press to disable"
                buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: PrimaryColor, borderRadius: 10}}
                titleStyle={{fontSize:13}}        
                onPress={disableButtonEG}                     
/>
```

Any assist is appreciated

Comment: You have to change in the state and have to declare and change the state in disableButtonEG i.e this.setState({btnDisabled: true })

and in the Button you have to do like 

<Button
                disabled={this.state.btnDisabled} 
                title="Press to disable"
                buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: PrimaryColor, borderRadius: 10}}
                titleStyle={{fontSize:13}}        
                onPress={disableButtonEG}                     
/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons have a disabled attribute, you can set this to true or false to disable the button. You should also be using onClick instead of onPress.

Here is an example of one way to achieve what you are trying to do in ReactJS

```
import React from "react";
function App() {
  const [disable, setDisable] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <button disabled={disable} onClick={() => setDisable(true)}>
      Disable Button
    </button>
  );
}
export default App
```

EDIT: Disable via function

```
import React from "react";
function App() {
  const [disable, setDisable] = React.useState(false);
  function disableButton() {
     setDisable(true)
  }
  return (
    <button disabled={disable} onClick={disableButton}>
      Disable Button
    </button>
  );
}
export default App
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist, that helped. However, is it possible to disable a button by calling a function from onClick?

Comment: I edited my original post to include a way to do it via a function

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function App() {
  const [disable, setDisable] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <button disabled={disable} onClick={() => setDisable(true)}>
      Click me!
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think onPress handler exists in `button`.
Please try with `onMouseDown` instead of `onPress`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you wrote the function syntax wrong. If you are still having problems after fixing it, You can use state. For example, I have a disabled state which has an initial value of false

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
```

And a function that will change it to true

```
const disableButtonEG = () => {
    setDisabled(true);
};
```

Then modify the Button component like this

```
<Button
            title="Press to disable"
            buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: PrimaryColor, borderRadius: 10 }}
            titleStyle={{ fontSize: 13 }}
            disabled={disabled}
            onPress={disableButtonEG}
        />
```